# What is difference b/w invalidate() and postInvalidate()?

Tags: android

I am using PostInvalidate(40, Rect); means After 40 miliseconds it should again call the OnDraw()  but it seems it is  taking more than 40 miliseconds in calling onDraw().

Shall I invalidate() this on timer or handler. It is necessary for me to call it within 40 miliseconds

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Cause an invalidate of the specified area to happen on a subsequent
>   cycle through the event loop. Waits for the specified amount of time.

Which means that the system will wait 40 milliseconds, then in a subsequent cycle through the event loop, it will do the invalidation.  If you have a slow event cycle, you will get a slow response to the invalidation.

That means that the time required for the invalidation to take effect is limited by how long it takes to cycle through your event loop.  It will never happen in 40 milliseconds.  Whatever average time it takes for an Invalidate() to work, it will take that amount of time + 40 milliseconds more (at least).